# self calling function inside variable php

Tags: php, function, variables, functional-programming

I am trying to return the value of self calling function into variable that I will use later but get the following error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'**

any idea what am i doing wrong? Is it the way to do that? Here is the code:

```
$clientText = call_user_func(function(){
    if($lang == 'en'){
    return <<<END
    <p>hello world</p>  
END;
    } else {
             ...
        }
});
```

thank you.

### update

Just found that my php version is 5.2. Is it still possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under php 5.2:

Nothing can stop you define the function and then call it.

```
    function getClientText($lang){
        if($lang == 'en'){
        return <<<END
        <p>hello world</p>  
    END;
        } else {
                 ...
            }
    }
   $clientText = getClientText($lang);
```

Or just do it:

```
  $clientText =   $lang == 'en' ?  '<p>hello world</p>' : $something_else
```

Answer (score 0):

on my php this works (tested with 5.4 alpha 2):

```
$clientText = call_user_func(function($lang)
{

if($lang == 'en')
{
    return <<<END
    <p>hello world</p>  
END;
} else {}

}, 'en');

echo $clientText;
```

you probably don't have php 5.3, but php 5.2

Comment: uff, you absolutly right. phpinfo confirms PHP Version 5.2.17. But what is the way to do that under 5.2?

Comment: don't use anonymous functions :( or www.php.net/create_function that is not cool